# add new key to dict within method of class

Tags: python, class, dictionary, methods

I have a class defined as follows:

```
class Wallet:
    def __init__(self):
            self.address, self.key = get_account()

    def transact(self, function):
        block = w3.eth.get_block('latest')
        tx_params = dict(
            type=2,
            chainId=31337,
            maxFeePerGas=2 * block['baseFeePerGas'],
            maxPriorityFeePerGas=0,
            nonce=self.nonce,
        )
        tx_params.update(gas=2 * gas)

def main():
    wallet = Wallet()
```

After instantiating the Wallet class, is there a way to add a key to the dictionary `tx_params` ?

I would like to be able to do something like  `wallet.transact(function).tx_params['value'] = 6000`

Comment: Why does `tx_params` exist? Presumably you have some reason for building it, but you're not doing anything with it or saving it anywhere. Did you want to actually perform a transaction? Should `transact` return `tx_params`? It's not clear what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare `tx_params` as an attribute of Wallet, so:

```
class Wallet:
    def __init__(self):
            self.address, self.key = get_account()
            self.tx_params = None

    def transact(self, function):
        block = w3.eth.get_block('latest')
        tx_params = dict(
            type=2,
            chainId=31337,
            maxFeePerGas=2 * block['baseFeePerGas'],
            maxPriorityFeePerGas=0,
            nonce=self.nonce,
        )
        tx_params.update(gas=2 * gas)

def main():
    wallet = Wallet()
    wallet.transact(function)
    wallet.tx_params['value'] = 6000
```

Bear in mind that `wallet.transact()` must have been already called, so `tx_params` is initialized.